# django relational object selector

Tags: django, django-models

hello is there a better way to do this?

```
reply = Post(created_by = request.user.customuser_related.all()[0])
```

I just need the one and only `customuser` object from request.user,
I don't know if I should do a `customuser get(...)` instead of that all, but even then it seems like there is a more efficient way.

this line should be enough to explain what I am trying to accomplish, but I can add more information if I need to.  Thanks

Comment: if you do a `.get()` it gives an object only if 1 object is present. It would raise an exception if nothing is present, or multiple objects are present

Comment: Could you elaborate more on `customuser_related` and why only `[0]` is fetched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using the development version of 1.6, the QuerySet API was expanded with a [`first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.first) query:

```
reply = Post(created_by = request.user.customuser_related.first())
```

If not, then a related query on the `CustomUserManager` might be the cleanest way to go:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

class CustomUserManager(models.Manager):
    def for_user(user):
        try:
            return self.get(user=user)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return None

reply = Post(created_by = CustomUser.objects.for_user(request.user))
```